# Get screen shot on macOS from NetCore 3.1?

Tags: c#, macos, opengl, .net-core, sharpgl

I need to get a screenshot on macOS from netcore 3.1 app. Unfortunately current implementation of `System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen` thows `PlatformNotSupportedException`. But what other simplest way (maybe over OpenGL or GTK) get a screenshot?